# iPad Mini 3 - Removing standard built-in apps

Tags: icloud, music, macos

How can I remove the built-in music app from my iPad, or at least remove the icon.
 My daughter uses the iPad and I don't want her to have access to some of the music and radio stations.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot uninstall or hide the default Apple apps.

You can set up Restrictions [parental controls] to prevent access to particular apps or age-related content.

Word of warning - don't forget the passcode or you'll have to wipe the phone & start over.

Settings > General > Restrictions. Enable Restrictions & enter a passcode.

When an option is on, or you see a checkmark next to an item, that means you're allowing access to that item. Turn options off to restrict access.

**Apps and features**
Safari
Camera (also disables FaceTime)
FaceTime
iTunes Store
iBooks Store
In-App Purchases
Siri
AirDrop
CarPlay (available only with iPhone 5 or later)
Installing apps
Deleting apps

**Types of content**
Ratings (select the country in the ratings section to automatically apply the appropriate content ratings for that region)
Music and podcasts
Movies
TV shows
Books
Apps
Siri
Websites
If you don’t use Touch ID for paid and in-app purchases, you can choose between two options for how often you need to enter your password for these purchases.

**Changes to privacy settings**
Location Services
Contacts
Calendars
Reminders
Photos
Bluetooth sharing
Microphone
Twitter
Facebook
Advertising

**Changes to settings and accounts**
Accounts (you can prevent changes to Mail, Contacts, Calendars, iCloud, Twitter, Facebook, Vimeo, Flickr, iTunes, App Store, iMessage, and FaceTime)
Background app refresh
Find My Friends (available when you install the Find My Friends app)
Volume limit
Cellular data use (available only on cellular-enabled iOS devices)

**Features within Game Center**
Multiplayer games
Adding friends

Source:Apple KB [About Restrictions (parental controls) on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to disable the new (iOS 8.4+) Music app and turn the app back to its old state.

Settings > Music > Show Apple Music

This way, only songs bought in the iTunes Store will be available.